# Azure WebJobs SDK - What purpose does method ToInvokeString serve?

Tags: azure-webjobssdk

When implementing an `IValueProvider` in a custom WebJobs SDK extension, we are supposed provide implementation of method [ToInvokeString](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/bba8d6a69f77f3fea870082efcd540a138a788b4/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Bindings/IValueProvider.cs?q=toinvokestring%20path%3A%2F%5Esrc%5C%2FMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host%5C%2F%2F#L25-L29). When does the SDK call this method? What should be the considerations when implementing the method?

Comment: **_ToInvokeString_**:- Returns object string.
Please refer [Custom Extension](https://krvarma.medium.com/custom-extension-for-azure-functions-part-1-triggers-e88e4bc94669) and [IValueProvider.ToInvokeString](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IValueProvider.GetValueAsync%28%29/) for more details.

Comment: The method seems to be used for logging purpose, to prevent printing of unhelpful `System.Object` for converted values of object type. I might be wrong though. I tried to scan through WebJobs SDK code, but gave up after some time.

Answer (score 0):

- **ToInvokeString** will return the method's return value as an Object directly.
- ***ToInvokeString***:- Returns object string.

**Examples :**

```cs
 public string ToInvokeString()
 {
   return string.Empty;
 }
```

```cs
HttpRequestMessage request = value as HttpRequestMessage;
string invokeString = ToInvokeString(request);
```

Please refer [Custom Extension](https://krvarma.medium.com/custom-extension-for-azure-functions-part-1-triggers-e88e4bc94669) for more details.